# Interactive Sequence diagram using mermaid.js producing parse errors in Observable Notebooks

Tags: javascript, sequence-diagram, mermaid, observablehq

I tried creating an interactive sequence diagram inspired by
https://observablehq.com/@tomlarkworthy/animated-sequence-diagrams

The (required) diagram is as shown below:

[image]

However when I am trying to animate it(in the observable notebook) I am encountering parse errors.

```
mermaid`sequenceDiagram
    autonumber
    actor S as Student
    participant s as System
    participant ad as Admin(Librarian)
    participant b as Book database
    participant sdb as Student database
    ${includeIf(
      step > 0,
      `${includeIf(step === 1, `rect rgb(0,255,0)\n`)}
      S->>s: Login
      activate S
      activate s
      ${includeIf(step == 1, "\nend")}
      ${includeIf(
        step > 1,
        `${includeIf(step === 2, `rect rgb(0, 255, 0)\n`)}
            s->>sdb: Authenticate with login details
                        activate sdb
        ${includeIf(step == 2, "\nend")}
        ${includeIf(
          step > 2,`alt authenticated user
          ${includeIf(step === 3, `rect rgb(0, 255, 0)\n`)}
            sdb-->>s: user authenticated
            ${includeIf(step == 3, "\nend")}
          ${includeIf(
            step > 3,
            `${includeIf(step === 4, `rect rgb(0, 255, 0)\n`)}
              s-->>S: Login successful
            ${includeIf(step == 4, "\nend")}
            ${includeIf(
              step > 4,`else else
              ${includeIf(step === 5, `rect rgb(0, 255, 0)\n`)}
                sdb-->>s: authentication failed
              ${includeIf(step == 5, "\nend")}
              ${includeIf(
                step > 5,
                `${includeIf(step === 6, `rect rgb(0, 255,0)\n`)}
                s->>sdb: does the user exist?
              ${includeIf(step == 6, "\nend")}
              ${includeIf(step > 6,
                  `alt user doesn't exist
                ${includeIf(step === 7, `rect rgb(0, 255,0)\n`)}
                sdb-->>s: user does not exist
              ${includeIf(step == 7, "\nend")}
              ${includeIf(step > 7,
                `${includeIf(step === 8, `rect rgb(0, 255,0)\n`)}
                s->>S: Register?
              ${includeIf(step == 8, "\nend")}
              ${includeIf(step > 8,
                  `else else
                ${includeIf(step === 9, `rect rgb(0, 255,0)\n`)}
                sdb-->>s: user already exists
                                deactivate sdb
              ${includeIf(step == 9, "\nend")}
              ${includeIf(step > 9,
                `${includeIf(step === 10, `rect rgb(0,255,0)\n`)}
                s->>S: invalid credentials
              ${includeIf(step == 10, "\nend")}
                        end
                        end`
                      )}`
                    )}`
                  )}`
                )}`
              )}`
            )}`
          )}`
        )}`
      )}`
    )}
`
```

After observing closely I find that there needs to be an end statement immediately after an alt statement..but if I do so I would not get the required diagram.